# TagLib error while Importing files?

Tags: import

I am using Mathematica to import some flac files.These files will be imported by a script multiple times.There is an TagLib error on one of the files on the second import of it.The first import though was successful, any idea why is that and how to fix it?Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please provide a link to the offending file as well as the commands you are using to import it. Use Google Drive etc and make sure the link is public. If there is another file you can import successfully, include it as well. At this point you have not provided much for any potential respondent to work with. Thanks..